# No tableview after pushing a multivalue button in settings.bundle

Tags: ios, inappsettingskit

I added an "Settings.Bundle" and the InAppSettingsKit to my app which works half fine ;-)
My problem:
I added an MultiValue list to the Root.plist and if I push the button to go to this list I allways "fall back" to the MainView of my app.

This is what should happen:
MainView -> SettingsView -> "next View inside the Settings (MultiValue e.g.)" -> "MultiValue TableView".

This is what happens:
MainView -> SettingsView ->"next view inside the Settings" -> MainView

This happens only if I call the settings out of my app. If I go through "Settings->MyApp" everything is fine.

If I call the SettingsView with "setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl" and then push a button to go to an Multivalue list, I only see a black background und the up curled MainView and can not go back anymore.

Someone any idea where the missing part in my code could be !?

```
[self.appSettingsViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
UINavigationController *aNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]       initWithRootViewController:self.appSettingsViewController];

appSettingsViewController.showDoneButton = YES;
[self presentModalViewController:aNavController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Navigation code, please?

Comment: sorry I will post the code below

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `-modalTransitionStyle` for the Navigation Controller, not the View Controller.

```
UINavigationController *aNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]       initWithRootViewController:self.appSettingsViewController];
[aNavController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
appSettingsViewController.showDoneButton = YES;
[self presentModalViewController:aNavController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but now the MainView appears again ;-)

Comment: Well after I did that I can see that the MultiValue-View  appears for a short time but then the MainView come above the MultiVlaue-View...

Comment: OK I found it: When the first SettingsView will be closed, [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; is called .... If I uncomment this, the MultiValue-View appears.  Thats is ... The bad thing is the "Back" button is hidden by the curled window, so I have to choos a different transitionStyle ....